# ordered fields with the bounded value property

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic

Say that an ordered field $F$ satisfies the bounded value property if, for all $a < b$ in $F$ and for every continuous function $f$ from $[a,b]_F := ${$x \in F: a \leq x \leq b$} to $F$, there exists $B$ in $F$ such that $-B < f(x) < B$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]_F$.  (Here we say $f$ is continuous if it satisfies the usual $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition, where all quantification is over $F$.)

Does there exist a non-Archimedean ordered field with the bounded value property?

I show in http://jamespropp.org/reverse.pdf (see the second paragraph on page 9) that every Archimedean ordered field satisfying the bounded value property is isomorphic to the reals, but my proof that the bounded value property implies the Archimedean property (see the first paragraph on page 9) is incorrect (thanks to Ricky Demer for pointing out my mistake).

In attempting to fix my proof, I am starting to wonder if in fact the implication fails.  For instance, does the surreal number system have the bounded value property?  I don't see how to prove that it doesn't.

All I can show is that if $F$ satisfies the bounded value property and contains a cofinal set $S$ whose cardinality is less than or equal to that of the continuum, then $F$ is Archimedean.  (Proof: Let $g:[0,1] \rightarrow F$ be a function that takes on all values in $S$, and for all $x$ in $[a,b]_R$ with standard part $\overline{x}$ let $f(x) = g(\overline{x})$.  If $F$ is non-Archimedean, $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]_F$ and unbounded.)  But, even leaving aside constructivist qualms about how one constructs $g$ from $S$, clearly this approach won't work for the surreal numbers or for sufficiently large fields within the Field of surreal numbers.

Comment: related to your paper but not this question: For the cut property, wouldn't it be nicer to drop the condition that $A\cup B = R$ and use the second conclusion?

Comment: @Ricky: That was Tarski's feeling too. His version of the cut property is more flexible but I don't think students find it as intuitive, since the range of possibilities for the sets $A$ and $B$ becomes vastly greater. I personally find the narrower statement easier to visualize and hence more compelling, but that's purely an esthetic preference. If one were to develop real analysis from my version of the cut principle, your version should probably be Theorem 1!

Comment: @James, this is a reply to your latest comment on my answer, but the comments there were piling up. I cannot see how to eliminate AC from the proof given in my answer, if one uses the Schmerl method; and I suspect the same holds for Sikorski's construction. I am also a bit puzzled about requiring no use of $AC$ in the counterexample since **(1)** that was not specified anywhere in your question, and **(2)** there is very little to say about uncountable model theory and algebra in the absence of choice. – Ali Enayat 0 secs ago

Comment: @James: despite the pessimism expressed in my previous comment about eliminating the axiom of choice $AC$ , a "miracle has happened", and I can now see how to take advantage of a key feature of Schmerl's construction to eliminate $AC$; by tomorrow I will put a PS on my answer in which I will outline how this is done.

Comment: I don't see why that cardinal must be regular.  For that matter, I don't see why it can't have countable cofinality.

Comment: @Ricky: right, we need countable choice to make sure $\omega_1$ is a regular cardinal (and it is sufficient to work with $\omega_1$, the cardinal I used (the Hartogs of continuum) is overkill.

Comment: @Ricky: I forgot to thank you in my previous comment, I have edited my answer in light of it.

Comment: +1 for the answer, James should accept and upvote it.  (Also, do you need $AC_{\omega}$ for anything other than proving the existence of a regular uncountable aleph?)

Comment: @Ricky: Thanks for the feedback. I only used $AC_\omega$ to get hold of a regular uncountable aleph, as you suspected.

Comment: @James: I imagine you are busy on other fronts, but let me know if there are still any obscure part in my answer to your question (the PS is admittedly terse).

Comment: @Ali: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the last two weeks' comments on this thread until just now!  (I thought MathOverflow would alert me to them, but either it didn't or I wasn't paying attention.)  I think your argument is correct, and the only thing that leaves me dissatisfied is the reliance on countable choice.  Since my original posting didn't specify what axioms I wanted to use, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for taking the time to explain everything!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT NOTE:** A postscript  has been added to indicate why the answer does not change if one is forced to work in $ZF+AC_\omega$ (prompted by a query of James Propp). Thanks to James Propp, Ricky Demmer, and Emil Jeřábek for catching infelicities of the past versions.

> There are nonarchimedean fields with the bounded value property.

Let's begin with a key definition: an ordered field $F$ satisfies the **$\kappa$-Bolzano-Weiestrass property**, abbreviated $BW(\kappa)$, if every bounded sequence $x_\alpha$ of length $\kappa$ in $F$ has a convergent subsequence of length $\kappa$.

So the Bolzano-Weirestrass theorem says that $\Bbb{R}$ satisfies $BW (\aleph_{0})$.

> Sikorski (1948) proved that for every **uncountable** regular cardinal $\kappa$ there is an ordered field of cardinality and cofinality $\kappa$ that satisfies $BW(\kappa)$. Since every archimedean ordered field has countable cofinality, the following Lemma, when coupled with Sikorski's theorem above (with $\kappa$ chosen as $\aleph_1$) shows that nonarchimedean fields with the bounded value property exist.

Note that the proof is of the Lemma is an adaptation of the usual real-analysis proof of the boundedness of continuous functions on closed bounded intervals, using $BW (\aleph_{0})$.

**Lemma.** *Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal. If $F$ is an ordered field of cofinality $\kappa$ such that $F$ satisfies $BW(\kappa)$, then $F$ has the bounded value property.*

**Proof:**  Choose an increasing unbounded sequence $x_\alpha$ of elements of $F$, where $\alpha \in \kappa$. If $f[a,b]$ has no upper bound for a continuous function $f$, then for each $\alpha < \kappa$ there is some $t_{\alpha}$ $\in [a,b]$ with $f(t_{\alpha}) > x_{\alpha}$.

By $BW(\kappa)$ there is some unbounded subset $U$ of $\kappa$ such that the subsequence $S$ := {$ t_{\alpha} : x \in U $} converges to some $c\in [a,b]$. Therefore by continuity of $f$, the sequence $f(S)$ converges to $f(c)$.

But a convergent sequence of length $\kappa$ must be bounded (the regularity of $\kappa$, and the assumption that $F$ has cofinality $\kappa$ comes to the rescue here), and yet $f(S)$ is clearly unbounded by construction. This contradiction shows that $f[a,b]$ is bounded above; a similar reasoning shows that $f[a,b]$ is bounded below (or just replace $f$ by its absolute value). **QED**

**Some references**: Sikorski's Theorem appears in:

Roman Sikorski, *On an ordered algebraic field*. Soc. Sci. Lett. Varsovie. C. R. Cl. III. Sci. Math. Phys. 41 (1948), 69–96 (1950).

> A proof of Sikorski's theorem can also be found in the following paper (Cor. 2.7), as a corollary of a vast generalization of Sikorski's theorem; the paper is an impressive showcase for the interaction between deep methods of models of arithmetic and higher set theory with field theory.

James Schmerl, *Models of Peano arithmetic and a question of Sikorski on ordered fields*. Israel J. Math. 50 (1985), no. 1-2, 145–159.

> **PS**. One can show, using some machinery from the model theory of arithmetic, that working only in $ZF+AC_\omega$, Schmerl's proof can produce a *well-orderable* field $F$ of cardinality and cofinality $\aleph_1$ that satisfies $BW(\aleph_1)$. This allows one to  one obtain a non-archimedean field with the bounded value property, entirely within $ZF+AC_\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ali. The first place where I don't follow you is in your restatement of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Did you really mean to say that the ordered field has cardinality $\kappa$?  Note that the Bolzano-Weiestrass Theorem concerns sequences of length $\aleph_0$ chosen from a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$. So something seems amiss here.

Comment: @James, you are right, I should have just said: "the usual Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem", I will fix that.

Comment: @James: I ended-up removing any cardinality restrictions from $BW(\kappa)$ which does not effect my answer; but in case you look at Schmerl's paper note that he stipulates the cardinality of $F$ being greater than $\kappa$ as part of the definition of $BW(\kappa)$.

Comment: How do you get the third sentence of your proof?

Comment: I also appear to be missing something: doesn't Cantor's original (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof#The_proofs) proof show that any countable ordered field does _not_ satisfy $BW(\aleph_0)$ ?

Comment: @Ricky: Is "How do you get the third sentence of your proof?" addressed to me (presumably regarding the second paragraph on page 9 of my draft) or addressed to Ali (presumably regarding his reply to my post)?  (I never realized before how helpful those "@" signs can be!)

Comment: it   was   @Ali

Comment: @Ricky: I have now changed the definition of $BW(\kappa)$ so the third line of the answer is OK now; or did you mean the third line of the proof of the Lemma, stating that $f(S)$ converges to $f(c)$?

Comment: I meant the proof of the lemma, since $\langle x_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \kappa \rangle$ is unbounded and you appear to be applying $BW(\kappa)$ to it.

Comment: @Ricky: presumably it should read `$S:=\{t_\alpha:\alpha\in U\}$`. The sequence `$\{t_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$` is bounded indeed.

Comment: @Ricky and Emil: yes, those x's in S should be t's, it is now fixed. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The only problem is that the $t_{\alpha}$ haven't been assigned values yet.

Comment: @Ricky: I am not sure what you mean by "assigned values", I am implicitly using the axiom of choice to concoct $t_\alpha$.

Comment: So that's the missing step.  Then the result would be: if AC then there are non-archimedean ordered fields with the bounded value property.  (James is, after all, doing a sort of reverse mathematics.)

Comment: @Ricky: but the question posed was a question in (uncountable) model theory; whose meta-theory is usually taken as $ZFC$; without $AC$ most of uncountable model theory is lost.

Comment: I'm still processing Ali's answer. In the meantime, can anyone come up with an example of a non-Archimedean ordered field satisfying the bounded value property WITHOUT appealing to AC? Or is that asking too much?

Comment: I now understand and accept Ali's proof, modulo Sikorski's Theorem.  But instead of appealing to Sikorski's Theorem, could we perhaps use an explicit subfield of the Field of surreal numbers, such as the set of surreal numbers created prior to day $\omega_1$?  (Note that this non-Archimedean ordered field satisfies the Nested Interval Property.)

Comment: @James, thanks for your feedback; my suggestion is to close this question and pose you new question separately for maximal exposure.